# Css for tool tip in rope down menu

Tags: html, css

I want to make a tool tip for drop down but am having problem in the arrow please can some one position it the way i want it thank you

**Here is what i get**

[image: Error toottip]

**I want it to look like this**

[image: I want it this way]

Here is my CSS code

```
<style>
    #wrapper-err {
      position: absolute;
      display: inline-block;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      z-index: 2222;
      width:210px;
      height:90px;
      margin-top:2em;
      margin-left:2em;
}

.err-tip {
    background-color: #D03B3E;
    color:#fff;
    padding:0.5em;
}

.err-tip::before {
      content: "";
      width: 0; 
      height: 0; 
      border-left: 15px solid transparent;
      border-right: 15px solid transparent;
      border-top: 18px solid #D03B3E;
      position: absolute;
      top: -18px;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -4px;
      display: block;

}

.err-tip div{
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px none;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    outline: medium none;
}
.err-close{
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  right: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px dotted;
  margin: 0.2em;
}
.err-tip p{
  margin-right: 0.4em;
  margin-top: 0.4em;
  margin-bottom: 0.4em;
}

</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="err-tip" id="wrapper-err">
    <span class="err-close">X</span>
    <p>hfdbmxvncbv jkjfvkbcjkjzcjxvbckjkjzckxvjbc.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change the arrow border like this:

```
.err-tip::before {
      content: "";
      width: 0; 
      height: 0; 
      border-left: 15px solid transparent;
      border-right: 15px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 18px solid #D03B3E; /* changed from top to bottom */
      position: absolute;
      top: -18px;
      right: 25px; /* change the horizontal position */
      margin-left: -4px;
      display: block;
}
```

Here is a snippet:

```css
 #wrapper-err {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 2222;
    width:210px;
    height:90px;
    margin-top:2em;
    margin-left:2em;
}

.err-tip {
    background-color: #D03B3E;
    color:#fff;
    padding:0.5em;
}

.err-tip::before {

      content: "";
      width: 0; 
      height: 0; 
      border-left: 15px solid transparent;
      border-right: 15px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 18px solid #D03B3E;
      position: absolute;
      top: -18px;
      right: 25px;
      margin-left: -4px;
      display: block;

}

.err-tip div{
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px none;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    outline: medium none;
}
.err-close{
float: right;
position: absolute;
top: 1px;
right: 1px;
cursor: pointer;
border: 1px dotted;
margin: 0.2em;
}
.err-tip p{
margin-right: 0.4em;
margin-top: 0.4em;
margin-bottom: 0.4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="err-tip" id="wrapper-err">
  <span class="err-close">X</span>
  <p>the text.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @Micheal glad to help :)